# How to set the content type header in response for a particular file type in Pyramid web framework

Tags: python, pyramid

I am using pyramid web framework to build a website. I keep getting this warning in chrome console:

> Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "http:static/images/fonts/font.woff".

How do I get rid of this warning message?

I have configured static files to be served using `add_static_view`

I can think of a way to do this by adding a subscriber function for responses that checks if the path ends in `.woff` and setting the response header to `application/x-font-woff`. But it does not look like a clean solution. Is there a way to tell Pyramid to do it through some setting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pyramid uses the standard [`mimetypes` module](http://docs.python.org/library/mimetypes.html) to guess the mimetype based on the extension. It calls:

```
mimetypes.guess_type(path, strict=False)
```

The module looks in the Windows registry if on that platform, and in the following locations for mimetype lists:

```
knownfiles = [
    "/etc/mime.types",
    "/etc/httpd/mime.types",                    # Mac OS X
    "/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types",               # Apache
    "/etc/apache/mime.types",                   # Apache 1
    "/etc/apache2/mime.types",                  # Apache 2
    "/usr/local/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types",
    "/usr/local/lib/netscape/mime.types",
    "/usr/local/etc/httpd/conf/mime.types",     # Apache 1.2
    "/usr/local/etc/mime.types",                # Apache 1.3
    ]
```

You can either extend one of those files, or create your own file and add it to the module using the `.init()` function.

The file format is simple, just list the mimetype, then some whitespace, then a space-separated list of extensions:

```
application/x-font-woff     woff
```

Comment: For windows, open regedit, open the key `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\` add a key for `.woff` and set the `Content Type` to `application/x-font-woff`

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this following code where your Pyramid web app gets initialized.

`import mimetypes
mimetypes.add_type('application/x-font-woff', '.woff')`

For instance, I have added it in my webapp.py file, which gets called the first time the server gets hit with a request.

Comment: This answer could use some explanation for where to put this code and how it helps.